# quickblox session registration fails on simulator with no descriptive response (on sample IOS apps)

Tags: ios, quickblox

Is there a way to get more details on a quickblox QBResponse object, I'm running the simple-sample-users IOS app on the simulator, and its failing on the creation of the initial session,
    `[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:`

However, when I run it on the real device it works fine. On simulator it just says response.description is null and response code of 0 which does not match any of the QBResponse types

```
`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, QBResponseStatusCode){
QBResponseStatusCodeUnknown             = -1,
QBResponseStatusCodeAccepted            = 202,
QBResponseStatusCodeCreated             = 201,
QBResponseStatusCodeNotFound            = 404,
QBResponseStatusCodeOK                  = 200,
QBResponseStatusCodeBadRequest          = 400,
QBResponseStatusCodeServerError         = 500,
QBResponseStatusCodeUnAuthorized        = 401,
QBResponseStatusCodeValidationFailed    = 422
```

};`

Answer (score 0):

Please check for *response.error.reasons dictionary* or for *response.error.error.localizedReceoverySuggestion* to get more information about error.